# Why splitting material is breaking shading?

Tags: materials, shaders

I can't understand, I have a character where hair's mesh have one material for haircut, eyelashes and eyebrows:
[image]
I'm trying to split this material (by assigning verticies of eyebrows to a new material slot) so I'll be able to change color of eyebrows without changing color of eyelashes and hair, but when I'm doing it the alpha pin is breaking:
[image]

Why is this happening and how to fix that?

Comment: Check Material Properties > Settings > Blend Mode ... (it is probably set to Opaque) ... if it is not your case share your simplified blend, just a part of eyebrow if issue persists.

Comment: In your first screenshot, the material is set to _Blend Mode_ > _Alpha Hashed_ which is okay. Make sure the new material is the same, so I agree with @vklidu here. Another thing is, if there is an alpha channel or map or whatever kind of mask, make sure it is still placed correctly and not somehow moved so that the transparent part has changed its location.

Comment: @vklidu yes, the problem was in Blend mode - the Alpha Hashed is right mode for this. Thank you! Can you post it as answer, so I can mark it?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yes, alpha hashed settings helped, thank you!

Comment: Great it helped ...